# fuzzy matching on first name

Tags: r

In R, I have a first dataframe with a column named "name" containing strings including first names, surnames and employement of people. I have also have a second dataframe with a column named "preusuel" containing only first names. How can I join the two DF based matching first names ?

What I tried without success.

```
# Install the fuzzyjoin package if not already installed
# install.packages("fuzzyjoin")

library(fuzzyjoin)
library(dplyr)

# Suppose your dataframes are named df1 and df2 with the columns "name" and "preusuel" respectively
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Doctor John Doe", "Jane Smith", "Assistant manager Alice Johnson"))
df2 <- data.frame(preusuel = c("John", "Bob", "Alice"))

# Using fuzzy matching with stringdist_left_join
result <- stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("name" = "preusuel"), method = "jaccard", max_dist = 0.2)
```

My result :

| name | preusuel |
| --- | --- |
| Assistant Manager John Doe | NA |
| Jane Smith | NA |
| Doctor Johnson Alice | NA |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this using `grep` instead?

```r
df1 <- data.frame(name = c("Doctor John Doe", "Jane Smith", "Assistant manager Alice Johnson"))
df2 <- data.frame(preusuel = c("John", "Bob", "Alice"))

found <- sapply(df2$preusuel, \(s) {
  pat <- paste0("\\<", s, "\\>")
  i <- grep(pat, df1$name)
  if(length(i)) i else 0L
})

df1$preusuel <- NA_character_
df1$preusuel[found] <- df2$preusuel[found]
df1
#>                              name preusuel
#> 1                 Doctor John Doe     John
#> 2                      Jane Smith     <NA>
#> 3 Assistant manager Alice Johnson    Alice
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Your maximum distance is too low

```r
stringdist_left_join(df1, df2, 
    by = c("name" = "preusuel"), 
    method = "jaccard", max_dist = 0.7)

#>                             name preusuel
#> 1                 Doctor John Doe     John
#> 2                      Jane Smith     <NA>
#> 3 Assistant manager Alice Johnson    Alice
```

other values I've tried often get false positives or match fewer people. You'll need to play around with different methods and distances to see what works best for your data